# Having wifi crash issues after rebooting dell lattitude 3490 ubuntu 16.04 LTS 4.4.0.139 generic kernel

Tags: wireless

Having wifi crash issues on rebooting after 16 march 2019 dell lattitude 3490 ubuntu 16.04 LTS 4.4.0.139 generic kernel System.

Plz suggest...
Prabashis,
India

Comment: Attaching an error message would be helpful or the wireless card model and drivers installed if any.

Comment: Look at the logs, with `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`